# How to handle this Type MisMatch found List required Entity spring Boot JPA

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpql

> I create a  some operations in my controller class ,I want to store
> the results what i get from the operation but when I store these list
> of things it show me an error like Below

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
DepositMaterial!
Found:
List<Result>
```

> Here is my controller class

```
@PatchMapping("/pendingValue")
    fun  pend(@ModelAttribute request:ReqFindPending):ResponseEntity<*>{
        val existingWithdraw = depositRepository.findPendingByWithDrawId(request.withDrawId)
        if (existingWithdraw != null){
           val upPending = depositRepository.getPending(withDrawId = request.withDrawId)
            depositRepository.save(upPending)
            return ResponseEntity(ResMessage("Pending update successfull"),HttpStatus.OK)
        }else{
            return ResponseEntity(ResMessage(" id getting null value"),HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
        }

    }
```

> My repository

```
package com.nilmani.workload.repository

import com.nilmani.workload.entity.DepositMaterial
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam

interface DepositRepository : JpaRepository<DepositMaterial, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT wm.quantity ,dd.totalDeposit,wm.quantity -dd.totalDeposit AS pending FROM WithdrawMaterial wm INNER JOIN  DepositMaterial dd ON wm.id = dd.withDrawId ")
    fun getPending(@Param("withDrawId")withDrawId: Long?):List<Result>
}
```

> Here is my result Model

```
data class Result(
    val pending: Long,
    val quantity: Long,
    val totalDeposit: Long
)
```

> DepositMaterial Entity Class

```
package com.nilmani.workload.entity

import com.nilmani.workload.enum.Material
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id

@Entity
data class DepositMaterial (
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val id:Long=-1,
    val withDrawId:Long=-1,
    val totalDeposit:Long=-1,
    val material:Int= Material.NONE.type,
    val depositTime:LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
    val pending:Long = -1,
    val isDeposited:Boolean=false,
    )
```

> What is the reason for this issue,I want to only return these three
> things, and store the result subtraction result of totalDeposit and
> quantity in pending column to update the  table but , It give me error
> to store the depositMaterial

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a list of Results from `getPending`, not an individual DepositMaterial. But the `save` method requires a single object to save. Try only requesting one object from `getPending` by changing the return signature.

Answer (score 0):

```
depositRepository.getPending
```

returns a list of Entities.

```
depositRepository.save(upPending)
```

takes a single Entity to save in the database.

Solution:

Either change your `save(upPending)` method to `saveAll(upPending)`, or update your `getPending` repo method to return a unique Entity object.